# Plotting density chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a density chart. Below you can see data and chart

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'type_sale':[100,200,400,400,200,400,300,200,210,300],
        'bool':[0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1],
        }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['type_sale',
                                      'bool'])

df1['bool']= df1['bool'].astype('int32')
```

I tried with the command above but is not working. Can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

```
plot_density_chart(df1[['type_sale', 'bool']], "bool", 'type_sale',
                    category_var="type_sale", title='prevalence', 
                    xlabel='Type_sale', logx="Yes", vline=None, 
                    save_figure_name = 'type_sale_prevalence.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `seaborn` to plot the density chart:

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.FacetGrid(df1,hue='bool')
g = g.map(sns.kdeplot,'type_sale',fill=True,alpha=0.3)                      
g.add_legend()
g.fig.suptitle('Prevalence', fontsize=16)
g.axes[0,0].set_xlabel('Type_sale')
```

Which gives you the figure:
[image]
If you want to set x-axis to log, add this :

```
g.axes[0,0].set_xscale('log')
```